# How to workaround JMicron 1394 chip

Tags: laptop

I have a HP 8560w with JMicron FireWire chip which does not support my Presonus Firestation dice drivers.I've been looking at e-sata or usb3 to 1394 cards.Any Ideas?

Comment: eSATA to IEEE 1394? That seems a pretty weird conversion. Googling for it I can not find such a device. Just card accepting or using both. None which convert between a disc specific interface and universal serial link.

Answer (score 1):

According to the spec of your device on the HP homepage it has 1 Express Card/54 slot.

If you have problems with the built in 1394 chip you can buy an express card that provides 1394 connection(s). Depending on the concrete problem you have (which is not mentioned in your question) ad the chipset used by the express card this may solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Robert I'am looking at a Rain express card built for this.